# Why am I being followed by a political opponent in Twitter?

Tags: twitter

Why would an influential political figure follow me in Twitter, when I'm a nobody, and all I've done to date is opposed his party's philosophy? He follows some 100k people, with a similar number of followers.

I'm almost certain it's to benefit his party, his politics, and his own interests, rather than mine! But what is this actually achieving for him?

Surely he'd be better off following people of an aligned ideology! Otherwise he'd have 100k people filling his feeds with hate. (Actually, he probably does)

**Edit**: Thank you for the answer. I suspect it's a bit more than just getting any followers - at the least, because following people of opposing view won't do that as often as following people with aligned views. I'd need to do more examination or need more data to enable other possible answers.

If someone provides a better answer, I will select it.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

He (read: his account) might be following you with the hope that you'll follow him back. I doubt he or his social media team have actually checked what Tweets you have posted, liked or retweeted; rather, they are using a script to see which Twitter accounts have interacted with his account in the past, and just follow them all.

Following somebody doesn't cost anything, other than potentially clutter your timeline (but I doubt he's reading the entire timeline) and being somewhat vulnerable to hate mail via direct messages (which is easily reported/blocked). His real goal is probably to get as many followers as possible, and this is just one of the means.

Comment: He is probably not ready anyones timeline, he has a team to do that.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe he wants to know his negatives in society, He might be wanted to know where he is lacking. Following people and reading their feeds will help him know what is people thinking of him. Maybe the @Glorfindel answer is also correct.